# Ode to WRE (Rest In Peace)

Tags: riddle, wordplay, rhyme

> In many forms do I appear,
>   Some to the eye, some to the ear.
>   You've known me since you were a babe;
>   I'll be here when you're in the grave.
>   Some tame me and make works of art,
>   But most fall flat before the start.
>   I'm measured by meter and by foot.
>   You notice me in your own output.
>   It's fair to tell me that I am,
>   And a pest sometimes gets a slam.
>   Some think that ptero- went astray,
>   But it's just me there, plain as day.
>   If handling problems is what you must,
>   Like a baker, I'm a pro at crust.
>   Though insults I do not abide,
>   Slighting comments may hitch a ride.
>   By now you should my identity spy,
>   So tell me then: *who am I*?

Comment: [WRE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WRE)?

Comment: @randal'thor I'd clarify, but it would likely give away the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you are

> *poetry* or *verse*.

In many forms do I appear,
Some to the eye, some to the ear.

> There are many poetic forms, and some poems like [this one](https://www.poetryfoundation.org/poems-and-poets/poems/detail/44361) are intended to be seen as well as heard.

You've known me since you were a babe;
I'll be here when you're in the grave.

> Nursery rhymes. (And poetry is likely to be around for a good long time.)

Some tame me and make works of art,
But most fall flat before the start.

> There is a considerable gap between, say, William Shakespeare and William McGonagall.

I'm measured by meter and by foot.

> Poetic meter, which is made up of units called feet.

You notice me in your own output.

> From time to time, you may write a rhyme -- wouldn't you know it, you're a poet!

It's fair to tell me that I am,
And a pest sometimes gets a slam.

> I think we have puns here on "iamb" and "anapaest".

Some think that ptero- went astray,
But it's just me there, plain as day.

> Dactyl.

If handling problems is what you must,
Like a baker, I'm a pro at crust.

> Not sure what this is about -- it seems like there's a pun on "Procrustean" but so far as I know that doesn't refer to any particular feature of metre, though of course you could apply it to any case where someone forces writing to fit a particular verse form.

Though insults I do not abide,
Slighting comments may hitch a ride.

> I'm failing to understand this too. I suspect there's a term roughly synonymous with "slighting comments" that either also denotes a kind of verse or sounds like something that does.

By now you should my identity spy,
So tell me then: who am I?

> As I said above: either poetry or verse.

I haven't yet figured out what's going on with the title.

Comment: The intended answer was "rhyme" itself, but there's no meaningful distinction to be made here, so I've marked this as correct. If nobody else can get those last two clues, I'll explain them here.

Comment: Well, "rime" can mean "crust"; was the suggestion of a pun on "procrustean" coincidence?

Comment: Procrustean is exactly what was intended. Oddly enough, wikipedia doesn't have a page for the thing that couplet was referring to, so it might not be as well known as I thought.

Comment: Hmm, OK. Then I will be interested to find out. I don't think it's a term I've encountered before with a poetry-specific meaning.

Comment: (FWIW I just pulled a poetry reference book -- admittedly a small one -- off my shelf and looked in it, and didn't find anything listed under "procrustean"...)

Comment: I'd love to know who or what WRE is, too. I had a bit of a search for relevant people who died either recently or on the 5th or 6th of October in any year, and didn't find any.

Comment: Only person that seems to fit by initials from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_poets#E is [Waldo Ralph Emerson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ralph_Waldo_Emerson) whose initials were actually RWE.

Comment: Yeah, I did also look at a list of poets and didn't find anything more convincing than Emerson. He's not really even primarily thought of as a poet, at least not by me, and his birth and death dates aren't anything particularly relevant, and given that the initials are the wrong way around I'd be quite surprised if he's our target.

Comment: (I also wondered whether WRE RIP was an anagram of anything, but if so my brain is failing to oblige.)

Comment: Ok, I just did a quick search, and my rhyming dictionary failed to materialize. It's a bit too late for me to turn over my whole room, so you can expect a full explanation of Procrustean rhyme tomorrow. As for the elusive WRE, has anyone taken a look at my profile page?

Comment: Willard R Espy, eh? Fair enough. I am not familiar with his work (at least not his poetry; I think I have come across him before in the context of wordplay).

Comment: I found a page on the internet that uses the term "procrustean rhyme" to mean using enjambment to create word-splitting rhymes for words that would otherwise be unrhymable. (E.g., Tom Lehrer, who was a master of these, was challenged to rhyme "orange" and paired it off with "bizarre enj-" to be followed of course by "-oyment".)

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan That is indeed what I was referring to. And since my rhyming dictionary is nowhere to be found, I have ordered a new copy. I'll take a picture of Espy's definition once it arrives.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is

> DACTYL.

*In many forms do I appear,

Some to the eye, some to the ear.*

> The word has [several different meanings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dactyl), some of which (fingers) are visible to the eye while some (the poetry term) are most easily detectable in spoken words.

*You've known me since you were a babe;*

> This refers to the **finger** meaning of the word.

*I'll be here when you're in the grave.*

> Finger bones.

*Some tame me and make works of art,

But most fall flat before the start.

I'm measured by meter and by foot.*

> This refers to the poetic term "dactyl", which is a **foot** in poetic **meter**.

*You notice me in your own output.*

> I've written many a poem in my time.

*It's fair to tell me that I am,

And a pest sometimes gets a slam.*

> Not quite sure about these lines.

*Some think that ptero- went astray,

But it's just me there, plain as day.*

> [Pterodactyls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pterodactylus) - this line was what first put me on to the solution.

*If handling problems is what you must,

Like a baker, I'm a pro at crust.*

> Not sure about these lines. Maybe the fact that fingers are used for making crusts when baking?

*Though insults I do not abide,

Slighting comments may hitch a ride.*

> Giving the middle finger (US) or two fingers (British) to someone?

*By now you should my identity spy,

So tell me then: who am I?*

> You are a dactyl.

Comment: I was thinking probably something a little more general. (Answer still being written. But I wondered about yours too and might change my mind...)

Comment: @Gareth I just finished adding my explanation.

Comment: I still like mine better. But there are annoying gaps I'm still trying to fill.

Comment: Very clever! But not quite right-- the missing parts are in the lines you couldn't figure out.